# Mac mini - how to properly shut down External Drives

Tags: hard-drive, mac, external-hard-drive

I have a Mac mini that I use for development.  I have 2 external drives.
One contains my docker data / images and the other is for apps that take up too much space on the Mac.
My problem is that whenever I (re) start up my computer, it freezes / hangs.
As soon as I unplug the drives, and reboot again, it's fine.

I'd like to know how to configure my Mac so that I don't have to unplug everytime I reboot.

What I've checked so far:

- Startup Disk setting - set to "Macintosh HD" and not either of the
  external drives

Not sure what else I should check.

Comment: How long have you given it to complete shutdown? I have a Mac Pro with a *lot* of drives attached & sometimes it can take 5 minutes. Does it hang at black screen with spinny icon or cursor, or does it not get that far?

Comment: it's more when it's booting up.  it will sit there forever until I remove the drive.